# Calculate a ID for a cell based on x and y

Tags: c#, math, grid, coordinates, cell

I'm calculating a ID for a grid cell like this:

```
id = x * 65536 + y;
```

Trying to calculate x and y for a ID I do this:

```
x = id / 65536;
y = id - (x * 65536);
```

This works, as long as Y is bigger than 0. If Y is negative, I have to calculate it like this:

```
x = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)id / 65536.0);
y = id - (x * 65536);
```

How do I know if I have to round up or down before knowing what y is? Is there a better way to generate one ID for a cell based on x and y? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but after hours of tracking down strange errors to rounding problems, my brain is not working.

Comment: What is the range of possible values of y?

Comment: Is it a requirement that your ID be an Int?  You could easily do something like 1x2y and have it be unique and save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that 30,000 > y > -30,000, you could do this:

```
x = (id + 30000) / 65536
y = id - (x * 65536)
```

If 65536 > y > -65536 then:

```
id = x * 131072 + y

x = (id + 65536) / 131072
y = id - (x * 131702)
```

Comment: Please note that y cannot equal 65536.

Answer (score 1):

You said in the comments that y can take a value from -65336 to 655536. In that case you should use:

```
id = x * 131072 + y; // 131072 = 2^17
```

For otherwise let, id be 100000, then this could be translated to two different coordinates:

```
100000 == 1 * 65536 + 34464  // x = 1, y = 34464
100000 == 2 * 65536 - 31072  // x = 2, y = -31072
```

So if the range of y is -65536 up to and including 65535, then you should use

```
id = x * 131072 + y;
```

and to convert back, you should use the solution that [grc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645956/grc) proposed:

```
x = (id + 65536) / 131072;
y = id - (x * 131072);
```

Answer (score 0):

If C# has modulo (presumably the `%` operator), use that. (I'm assuming x and y are integers.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
    UInt16 x = 123;
    UInt16 y = 456;

    UInt32 Point;

    // encode y high, x low
    Point = (UInt32)(x | (y << 0x10));

    // decode
    x = (UInt16)(Point & 0x0000FFFF);
    y = (UInt16)((Point & 0xFFFF0000) >> 0x10);
```

Comment: I probably shouldn't have used Point.  There is already a Point defined in System.Drawing.